# Difference between two time stamps using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, datetime

I am trying to search an SQL database of incident tickets with two columns having timestamps. Now need to determine time difference between Referred Date and Resolved Date of each ticket.

So far, I managed to build a custom function and run below query successfully with some reference. How do I find time difference and then display difference as separate column in output?

```
$users = Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\users.txt

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $filterDate = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-1)

    Get-CdPacPro -ResolvedByGroup MyGroup -ResolvedByELID $user |
        Where-Object {$_.ResolvedDate.Date -ge $filterDate} |
        Select-Object ProblemID,ClosedByELID,ClosedByGroup,ResolvedDate,ReferredDate 
}
```

Comment: `...,ReferredDate` -> `...,ReferredDate,@{n='Difference';e={($_.ResolvedDate.Date - $filterDate).Days}}`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers You should add that as an answer :)

Comment: Oui, mon capitaine! ;þ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff730948(v=technet.10)) for adding a new field with the difference between two timestamps:

```
... | Select-Object ProblemID, ClosedByELID, ClosedByGroup, ResolvedDate,
   ReferredDate, @{n='Difference';e={($_.ResolvedDate.Date - $filterDate).Days}}
```

Comment: oh man. you have single handedly solved multiple doubts and need to re-edit my old scripts. :)

But I forgot to mention  that the ReferredDate and Resolved Dates are in DateTime format. Ex: 06/19/2019 12:02:56 AM

Does it still work in this case?

Comment: @JsJ `ResolvedDate` does not appear to be a date string, otherwise the comparison in your `Where-Object` clause would probably fail. And `ReferredDate` is not used in the calculation.

Comment: A little confused now. In the original script, I wanted to search for records from today and goes back till 'n' number of previous days. I hope I got it right in this expression "Today.AddDays(-n)"

That has actually worked for me as I wanted. If today is 19th and n is -1, It is returning records of 19th and 18th as I wanted. Note, 18 and 19 are resolved dates, as I am sure you got it. Referred date is now generated in the output, it doesnt exist before executing the script. So what  I want is to take referred date from output and calculate difference between referred date and resolved date.

Comment: @JsJ What are you talking about? `ReferredDate` is straight from the code snippet you posted. I have no idea where it comes from (well, obviously it's coming from `Get-CdPacPro`, but I know nothing about that cmdlet either) or what value it has.